# pasing values to rails controller from javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I want to pass one variable from javascript in rails view to the controller along with other form parameters.(rails 2.3.5)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function confirmation(){
    var x=confirm("Edit all copies?");
    //passing x and other form object (here @book)
   }
</script>
```

can I convert x to rails variable? if yes,how?

Comment: Have you considered using AJAX?

Comment: @Ashwin Balamohan : when I used ajax request, only x reaching. I dont know how to pass form object with that request.

Comment: Ah, OK. The trick would be to construct an object out of your form data, and to send that along through the AJAX call. See my answer, below. Does that solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest constructing an object that represents your form data (using jQuery) and using an AJAX function to pass that along to the server.

E.g.

```
var name = $("input#first-name").val();
var age = $("input#last-name").val();

var person = {
  name: name || "<no name entered>",
  age: age || 0
};

var url = "http://somewhere.com";

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: person
}).done(function() {
    console.log("Success");
});
```